# Angular double-curly expressions as an array

Tags: angularjs

I have `vm.someVal = []` which holds multiple **true/false** values like `vm.someValue[true, true, false]`. Then I pass `vm.someVal` to another directive via scope and render it inside brackets `{{vm.someVal}}`.

My question is how can I check if `vm.someVal` is true or false? For example if `vm.someValue[true, true, true]` I want to activate ng-disabled but no matter if `vm.someValue[true, true, true]` or `vm.someValue[true, true, false]` or even `vm.someValue[false, false, false]` it want make `{{vm.someVal === true}}` true.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive add a `function` where you check the conditions you want

```
function checkConditions(someInput){
   return someInput.every(function(value){
     return value;
   })
}
```

And apply it like (make appropriate changes)

```
ng-disabled = checkConditions(vm.someVal)
```

I used [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) based on your case but you can update it to best fit your problem.